# Show the comutativity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Omega$ be the set of some $n\times n$ matrices with the property $$A,B\in \Omega\Rightarrow AB\in\Omega, (AB)^3=BA.$$ Show that $AB=BA,\forall\ A,B,\in \Omega$.

What I could show now is $AB^2=AB B=(BA)^3B=B(AB)^2AB=(BA)^3B=AB^2$..But what about $AB=BA$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(ABABAB)^3 = [ (AB) (AB AB) ]^3 = (AB AB )(AB)  = (AB)(AB)(AB) = (AB)^3 = BA$

$(ABABAB)^3 = [(ABABA)B]^3 = B(ABABA) = (BA)(BA)(BA)= (BA)^3 = AB $

Then AB = BA